# Is it possible to take a partial payment of an order in Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2, plugin-ventievents

I have a request from a client to be able to take deposits for events purchased through craft commerce. These are high ticket items and customers would like to spread the cost of payment over several weeks/months before the event.

Is this something that is possible using craft commerce?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with a custom adjuster via a module or plugin.

Comment: From the docs "Adjustment models contain an amount which modifies the price of the order or line item.". I'm not sure if this is what I need as I don't want to change the order total. For example, lets say an event costs $4000 to attend but in order to reserve a place the customer would need to pay a deposit of $250 and then make sure the remaining balance is paid in full 4 weeks before the start date of the event. I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: From Luke Holder via email support on Mar 18, 2019:
"You could write your own payment controller endpoint (accepting a custom amount) using the current one as your inspiration, but you would need to take care of marking the order as complete yourself, since it won't be marked as complete automatically with a partial payment.

Once the first payment is made, the second payment could use the standard payment controller as it will only pay the balance."

Comment: We went another direction and wrote this into a site module where the admins can define which events allow deposits and what that deposit % is via custom fields: https://ssdd.d.pr/EGngT7

Comment: Thats great @StephenCallender, thanks for sharing the code and your approach, i'll take a look.

Comment: Hey @StephenCallender Can you share the code with me too please? above url is not working..